# calculate working days (excluding sundays)

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT DATE_PART('DAY',"repairClose"-"createdOn")::INTEGER as "noOfDays"
FROM "mstRecord"
WHERE "repairClose" is not null
```

I tried above query, it returns the result including sundays. I want result by excluding sundays.

Comment: What is your database structure?

Comment: @yanman1234 the above mentioned columns have timestamp with time zone as a data type

Answer (score 0):

try using `extract(dow from "column") <> 0`

here is an example:

```
t=# with dates as (select generate_series(now(),now()+'3 weeks'::interval,'1 day'::interval) "repairClose", now() "createdOn")
select "repairClose"-"createdOn","repairClose"::date, "createdOn"::date 
from dates 
where extract(dow from "repairClose") <> 0;
 ?column? | repairClose | createdOn  
----------+-------------+------------
 00:00:00 | 2017-07-31  | 2017-07-31
 1 day    | 2017-08-01  | 2017-07-31
 2 days   | 2017-08-02  | 2017-07-31
 3 days   | 2017-08-03  | 2017-07-31
 4 days   | 2017-08-04  | 2017-07-31
 5 days   | 2017-08-05  | 2017-07-31
 7 days   | 2017-08-07  | 2017-07-31
 8 days   | 2017-08-08  | 2017-07-31
 9 days   | 2017-08-09  | 2017-07-31
 10 days  | 2017-08-10  | 2017-07-31
 11 days  | 2017-08-11  | 2017-07-31
 12 days  | 2017-08-12  | 2017-07-31
 14 days  | 2017-08-14  | 2017-07-31
 15 days  | 2017-08-15  | 2017-07-31
 16 days  | 2017-08-16  | 2017-07-31
 17 days  | 2017-08-17  | 2017-07-31
 18 days  | 2017-08-18  | 2017-07-31
 19 days  | 2017-08-19  | 2017-07-31
 21 days  | 2017-08-21  | 2017-07-31
(19 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with gs(d) as (
    select d::date
    from generate_series (
        (select min("createdOn") from "mstRecord"),
        (select max("repairClose") from "mstRecord"),
        '1 day'
    ) gs (d)
)
select (
    select count(*)
    from gs
    where
        "createdOn" <= d and "repairClose" > d
        and
        extrat(dow from d) <> 0
) as "noOfDays"
from "mstRecord"
where "repairClose" is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

select
(SELECT count(*) AS count_days_no_weekend
FROM   generate_series("createdOn"::date, "repairClose"::date, '1 day') d(the_day)
WHERE  extract('ISODOW' FROM the_day) < 7) as "no_of_days"
from "mstRecord" where "repairClose" is not null
order by "no_of_days"

Here in postgres, Add "isodow" option to EXTRACT() where Sunday = 7, Monday=1, Tuesday=2 and so on.